# SDL2 [optimisation]: is SDL_Surface->texture->copy faster than drawing on renderer?

Tags: c, graphics, sdl

I'm wondering witch way is more efficient:

- modify RGB pixels data from a surface sized as the window, crate a texture from this surface then copy it on the render.

Or (what I use)

- SDL_SetRenderDrawColor + SDL_SetRenderDrawPoint directly in the double buffered Renderer, driven by a buffer array

I would prefer the first solution, but I would like to be sure before testing.
Thanks if you know SDL :)

Comment: Only way to be sure is to test it. Do a benchmark, compare results, and then ask a question if the result is unexpected. I am afraid there is currently too many unknown factors to answer your question reliably.

Comment: I've never heard of SDL_SetRenderDrawPoint before so can't comment on that. However it does depend on your use case scenario. If the data is fairly static then you could use `SDL_UpdateTexture` but if it is updating more often then you should look at using streaming textures. This will be faster than creating a texture every frame. See http://lazyfoo.net/tutorials/SDL/42_texture_streaming/index.php for an example

Comment: thanks for your answers, indeed, I need SDL_UpdateTexture using a streamed texture because I update every frame at 90fps it will be a lot faster than buffering colors for every pixel and draw point by point.

Answer (score 1):

When it comes to per-pixel things, manipulating an SDL_Surface's pixels is generally <strike>a little</strike> **way** faster than using SDL_RenderDrawPoint(). Of course, if that's just a pixel or two, it won't make a big difference, but filling an entire window could be **slow**. Turning this surface into a texture could take a little time, but not as much(On my computer, it adds about 2 ms per frames).

However, for as much as I know, your best option is to access the pixels of the screen's surface(SDL_GetWindowSurface()), and then to use SDL_UpdateWindowSurface().

I believe the SDL_RenderDrawPoint() slowdown is due to the extra time the CPU has to take to pass the pixels to the GPU(Maybe a software SDL_Renderer would act faster?).

Hope this helps.